# eclipselink 2.7.7 JPA Criteria API - how to call LISTAGG WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY...)

Tags: oracle, jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api, listagg

I need to call LISTAGG using the criteria api. I am calling it as shown below -

```
 criteriaQuery.multiselect(builder.function("LISTAGG", String.class, joinedTable.get("name")).alias("source"))
```

This is working with h2 test database but when oracle database is used, it throws exception `Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02000: missing WITHIN keyword\n\nError Code: 2000`.

I tried various combinations to pass WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY...) to builder.function("LISTAGG",....) but JPA throws exception.

Is it possible to pass `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY joinedTable.get("name")` to `LISTAGG` using the criteria api in eclipselink 2.7.7 ?

Comment: what is the SQL you get and what exactly do you need? You can build a LISTAGG expression within EcilpseLink's DatabasePlatform classes, but it is probably easier just to build the SQL as a string: cb.toExpression( cb.fromExpression(joinedTable.get("name"))
       .sql("LISTAGG( ? ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ? )", joinedTable.get("name")) )